# For what values of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ do $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z^n)$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+z^{2n})$ converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

> For what values of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ do $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  (1-z^n)$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  (1+z^{2n})$ converge?

I am trying to find these values of $z$ using the following definition/theorems. My intuition leads me to believe that for the case that $z$ is an $n$-th root of unity for some $n \geq 1$ we see that the product converges to $0$. Otherwise, if $z$ is not an $n$-th root of unity, we can find a subsequence with distances that do not tend to $0$, in which case the product diverges. For the second infinite product, I similarly suspect that if $z^{2n} = -1$ for some $n$ then the product tends to $0$ again and diverges otherwise. Is this the correct line of thinking? I have trouble formally writing this out with details, and also wanted to know other ways of approaching this problem.

**Theorem.**

Let $\text{Re } z_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n$ converges to a nonzero number iff
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log z_n$ converges.

**Theorem.**

Let $\text{Re } z_n > -1$. Then $\sum \log (1+z_n)$ converges absolutely iff $\sum z_n$ converges absolutely.

**Definition.**

If $\text{Re } z_n >0$ for all $n$ then $\prod z_n$ converges absolutely if $\sum \log z_n$ converges absolutely.

**Corollary.**

If $\text{Re } z_n >0$ then $\prod z_n$ converges absolutely iff $\sum (z_n - 1)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: The [Pentagonal Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) could probably help here.

Comment: $|z| < 1$ should do it in both cases by simple estimates - generally speaking in an infinite product the terms have to converge to 1 for the product to be called convergent (obviously that's not sufficient in general, but is necessary), though you have to be careful with zero factors which are generally accepted especially when you do infinite product of holomorphic functions, where zeros are isolated ; a product with terms going to zero is generally called divergent